# Store selectInput in a string/character object

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to store the variable in **input$var** to an object which can be compared to a string on the latter part. For now, I just tried to print it on the screen by storing it to an object **value_stored**. But it not printing anything*(Error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'*). That means it's not storing the value.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("censusVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create demographic maps with 
               information from the 2010 US Census."),

      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choose a variable to display",
                  choices = c("Percent White", 
                              "Percent Black",
                              "Percent Hispanic", 
                              "Percent Asian"),
                  selected = "Percent White")
      ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("selected_var")
      textOutput("test")
    )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste(input$var)
  })

  value_store <- reactive(input$var)

  output$test <- renderText({
   paste(value_store) 
  })

  # I want to use the value in input$var for some comparision. 
  # but value_store unable to store. Help.

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using [`reactiveValues`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html) (object to store your reactive values) and `observeEvent`.

Use server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    # Create object for reactive values 
    rv <- reactiveValues(
        value_store = character()
    )
    # When input changes -> update
    observeEvent(input$var, {
        output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
            paste(input$var)
        })
        rv$value_store <- input$var
        output$test <- renderText({
            paste(rv$value_store) 
        })
    })
}
```

PS: you can remove `paste` as it does nothing there.

Comment: This one worked. Thanks :) May I know if I have more than one selectInput, how to call all the stored object in the same block. Because out of observeEvent not able to fetch the stored_object.

Comment: @SangramkeshariSahu try using `observe({CODE})` instead of `observeEvent(input$var, {CODE})`

Comment: Awesome :) It helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to define the reactive element first and the watch the input inside an observeEvent() function. Then inside the observe you use isolate() to update the value.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("censusVis"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create demographic maps with 
           information from the 2010 US Census."),

  selectInput("var", 
              label = "Choose a variable to display",
              choices = c("Percent White", 
                          "Percent Black",
                          "Percent Hispanic", 
                          "Percent Asian"),
              selected = "Percent White")
  ),

 mainPanel(
   textOutput("selected_var")
   textOutput("test")
 )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  value_store <- reactive(val = '')

  observeEvent(input$var, {

    # add to reactive
    isolate(value_store$val = input$var)

    # or render update
    output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
       paste(value_store$val)
     })

  })




 output$test <- renderText({
   paste(value_store$val) 
 })

  # I want to use the value in input$var for some comparision. 
  # but value_store unable to store. Help.

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```