# Shiny dynamically select element in list and renderTable

Tags: r, list, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a list `l` of `data.frames`, and I want to dynamically select elements with `selectInput`.

Once the user selects an element, I'd like to be able work with it under the hood, for example use it in `renderTable` and output a table of that `data.frame`.

Moreover I'd like to be able to select that element in the list, and apply `lm` for example.

The problem I'm facing is here: `l[[ElemInput()]]` how do I convert this classic `R` code with a reactive element?

Here the complete `shinydashboard`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "My Dashboard"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("aaa", tabName = "aaa", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "aaa",
              h2("Dashboard aaa"),
              fluidRow(
                box(
                    selectInput("input_name", "Select input:", choices = names(l))
                ),
                box(
                  dataTableOutput('table')
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  # create a fake list 
  set.seed(123)
  l <- list(element1 = data.frame(aaa=1:5, bbb=sample(5)),
            element2 = data.frame(ccc=6:10, ddd=sample(5)))

  # reactive read element
  ElemInput <- reactive({
    input$input_name
  })

  # render table
    output$table <- renderTable({
      l[[ElemInput()]] #  this part doesn't work
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Possibly correlated questions but I couldn't figure out a solution for my case:

[dynamically list 'choices' for selectInput from a user selected column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248534/dynamically-list-choices-for-selectinput-from-a-user-selected-column?rq=1)

[Store selectInput in a string/character object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036649/store-selectinput-in-a-string-character-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `renderTable` with `tableOutput` in your `ui`. So change `dataTableOutput('table')` to `tableOutput('table')`.

You can use `dataTableOutput` if you use `renderDataTable` though.

Also my I prefer to use an observer instead of a reactive function. It's a bit easier to read.

```
server <- function(input, output) { 
  observeEvent(input$input_name,{
    # observe element change and render table
    output$table <- renderTable({
      data.frame(l[[input$input_name]])
    })
  })
}
```